# What does iOS Keychain error -26276 represent? (26276)

Tags: ios, keychain

This error code has been appearing in crash logs for a few users, but it seems to represent only a nondescript internal error: https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=26276

There's nothing in `SecBase.h` describing what it represents beyond that, either.

---

It may be situational, but I've heard something where there may be "dangling pointers in the Keychain when importing/exporting keys" or something? Not sure if this is at all accurate.